# Utility Class with static reference of a client

Tags: java

I came across a code where a utility class has a static reference of a client of a service. Here is the simplified version of the code

```
public class MyHelper {

  //assume that prime service checks if the number is prime
   private static PrimeService client; 

   public static void setClient(PrimeService client) {
       MyHelper.client = client;
   }

   public static boolean isIntegerPrime(int i) {
      return client.isIntegerPrime(i);  
   }
}
```

Any thoughts on the design of this class? Apart from accidently setting the client to null, I could not think of any downside of such utility classes with static references of remote service clients. I am interested in knowing the correctness of this class from design perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Your setMethod is of no use as it is not setting the static variabl.

```
    public static void setClient(PrimeService client) {
        client = client; //the assignment to this variable has no effect.    }
```

You need to change this to

```
   public static void setClient(PrimeService client) {
       MyHelper .client = client; 
   }
```

Comment: He said that above, "*Apart from accidently setting the client to null,*"

Comment: It is a nice habit to make all parameter final to avoid these mistakes.

Comment: Updated the code. Please note that this is a simplified version and not the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the client is set before the 1st call of "isIntegerPrime" you would not see any NullPointerExceptions.
You might get problems with parallel access to that client. Thus when synchronization is an issue.
If PrimeService is also under your control and usage like that is ok, it might also be an option to make the method in PrimeService static.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you might run into with this design (aside from concurrent access and the programming error mentioned in Juned's Answer) is that you might share state inadvertently. There is no way that `MyHelper` can be sure that the passed client reference is not used elsewhere. This might pose an encapsulation problem. Consider the concurrent access problem. Even if you make the method `isPrime(int i)` `synchronized`, some other thread might call `isIntegerPrime` on the `PrimeService` instance passed to `MyHelper`.